# yq append data to a yaml file inplace

Tags: yaml, yq

I have a YAML file file.yaml of this sort:

```
category: fruits
some_dummy_key: value
```

Now i would like to use Mike farah's yq v4(version 4.5.1 to be specific) https://github.com/mikefarah/yq to append `details` key inplace which has a list of name, color that should look like this:

```
category: fruits
somme_dummy_key: value
details:
- name: banana
  color: yellow
- name : apple
  color: red
```

In yq version, i know we could do a

```
./bin/yq write -i file.yaml details.[0].name banana

./bin/yq write -i file.yaml details.[0].color yellow
```

and so on. But how do i do it using yq v4's eval command. I really appreciate any help with this.

Comment: In mikefarah/yq, you could do below to append new objects under `.details`. Use the `-i` extension once you confirm the structure looks good. `yq e '.details += [ { "name": "banana", "color": "yellow" },{ "name": "apple",  "color": "red" }]' yaml`

Comment: Doesnt work for me. It throws an Error: !!seq ([]) cannot be added to a !!null
 error

Comment: I tested this on the YAML file provided in question on yq version 4.6.0, and it worked fine. Check if your file is different from what you posted

Answer (score 5):

Here is how it can be done. You will have to create a new root value called details and assign the parameters.

```
cbiswal@XXXXX:~$ cat tet.yaml
category: fruits
somme_dummy_key: value
cbiswal@XXXXX:~$ yq e '."details"+=[{"name":"mango","color":"yellow"},{"name":"apple","color":"red"}]' tet.yaml
category: fruits
somme_dummy_key: value
details:
  - name: mango
    color: yellow
  - name: apple
    color: red
```

Note that:

```
$ yq --version
yq version 4.7.0
```