# yq append multiple file into list yaml

Tags: yaml, yq

Assume I have a file `root.yml`

```
keyA: valA
keyB: valB
myList:
```

Then I receive some yml file, such as

`1.yml`

```
project_id: abc
description: xyz
```

`2.yml`

```
project_id: cba
description: zyx
```

And so on (they may stored in same folder)

Now I want to append the content of `1.yml`, `2.yml` (and so on) to the `myList` of `root.yml` and output to console

Expected:

```
keyA: valA
keyB: valB
myList:
  - project_id: abc
    description: xyz
  - project_id: cba
    description: zyx
  - (so on...)
```

I have searched some examples but they hard code the list item in the yq command, like this post: [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66266549/yq-append-data-to-a-yaml-file-inplace)

But I want it load from files, not from hard code
Please forgive for my bad english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq), you could use the load function with the filename of the YAML files to be included, i.e. with your example

```bash
yq '.myList += [ load("1.yaml"), load("2.yaml") ]' root.yml
```

producing a YAML result as

```yaml
keyA: valA
keyB: valB
myList:
  - project_id: abc
    description: xyz
  - project_id: cba
    description: zyx
```

As indicated in your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73469588/yq-append-multiple-file-into-list-yaml#comment129749948_73470863), if one of the object has a parent structure and you want to extract the element from it, you can do

```bash
yq 'load("1.yaml") as $f | .myList += [ $f.config[], load("2.yaml") ]' root.yml
```

Tested on `yq` version 4.27.2

Comment: Hi @Inian thank for your reply, how about if `1.yml` has a parent node wrapping all content, like `config:
  - project_id: abc
    description: xyz`  (`2.yml` keep as question)